# SFUserAccount is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I have updated my salesforcesdk-ios to new version 5.3.0. After logging in successfully, I set all these values in this delegate -**oauthCoordinatorDidAuthenticate:authInfo:** like this,

```
- (void) oauthCoordinatorDidAuthenticate: (SFOAuthCoordinator *) coordinator authInfo:(SFOAuthInfo *)info {

    [SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].coordinator = coordinator;
    [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] coordinator].credentials = coordinator.credentials;
    [[SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance] applyCredentials:coordinator.credentials];
}
```

When I try validating for the refreshtoken currentUser is nil in **- (void)send:(SFRestRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate shouldRetry:(BOOL)shouldRetry** and always loads salesforce login page instead of sending request to Salesforce.

**// If there are no demonstrable auth credentials, login before sending. SFUserAccount *user = [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].currentUser;**

user is always nil. How to set the useraccount correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide the salesforceSDK link which you are using in your app?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you could check the delegate **oauthCoordinatorDidAuthenticate:authInfo:** is worked. like:

```
- (void) oauthCoordinatorDidAuthenticate: (SFOAuthCoordinator *) coordinator authInfo:(SFOAuthInfo *)info {
print("delegate is worked")
[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager].coordinator = coordinator;
[[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] coordinator].credentials = coordinator.credentials;
[[SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance] applyCredentials:coordinator.credentials];
```

}

It could cause user is nil, when the delegate is not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. They are expecting to set currentUser explicitly in the newer version of iOS sdk. I have a custom login screen with toggle to switch between sandbox and production. I am setting user account now in this method like this -

```
   [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:^(SFOAuthInfo *authInfo,SFUserAccount *userAccount) {
        [SFSDKCoreLogger i:[self class] format:@"Authentication (%@) succeeded.  Launch completed.", authInfo.authTypeDescription];
        [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].currentUser = userAccount;
        [SFSecurityLockout setupTimer];
        [SFSecurityLockout startActivityMonitoring];
        s_loggedIn = YES;
    } failure:^(SFOAuthInfo *authInfo, NSError *authError) {
        [SFSDKCoreLogger e:[self class] format:@"Authentication (%@) failed: %@.", (authInfo.authType == SFOAuthTypeUserAgent ? @"User Agent" : @"Refresh"), [authError localizedDescription]];
    }];
```